# Table cellcolor: any way to paint only part of cell?

Tags: tables, color

I have a table where cells have borders and background colors. On some PDF readers the background colors sometimes get painted over the borders: [image: illustration of the problem]

I haven't been able to solve this and now I'm pondering other ways to represent the same data.

Many places recommend avoiding horizontal lines as much as possible, so I was wondering if I should modify this table by removing all horizontal lines (and the non-thick vertical lines) and **instead of painting entire cells, I would paint a small square or circle in the center of cells. Is that possible?**

Comment: I usually do not close questions. However, the fact that your previous, very similar question may make you worried that this question gets closed, too. Generally it is not appreciated if there is no starting point provided. You will get way more positive feedback if you post the code that produces the output you show, and explain what you have tried. (You may not like this comment but I am really only trying to help you get a valuable answer.)

Comment: you can use `\hfill` inside a cell to make the colour panel short but simpler is not to use `colortbl` at all and just put a coloured rectangle from eg `\textcolor{red}{\strut\hspace{1em}}` in the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is : (a) Use the `booktabs` package (b) instead of vertical rules, use some horizontal space between cells (c) instead of horizontal rules, use some like `\addlinespace[.2em]` to allow a similar space between rows. Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{K}{!{\color{white}\ }c}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cKKKKKK}\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Malware} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Shareware} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Etc...}\\\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
P1 & P2 & P3 & P4 & P5 & P6 & P7 \\\midrule
\rowcolor{yellow}
 &\cellcolor{red} & &  &  &  & \\\addlinespace[.25em]
\rowcolor{cyan}
& & &  &\cellcolor{olive}  &  & \\\addlinespace[.25em]
&  &  & \cellcolor{magenta}  &  &  & \\\addlinespace[.25em]
\rowcolor{gray!20}
&  &  & \cellcolor{magenta!20}  &  &  & \\\addlinespace[.25em]
& & & & & \cellcolor{magenta} & \cellcolor{magenta} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks amazing! So much better than what I had!

Comment: Compare the end result: [https://www.baobab.fi/random/latex_tables.jpg](https://www.baobab.fi/random/latex_tables.jpg) (also: let me know if u see something i could improve still)

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Look good `:)`